# angular material md-tab-content height not scrolling

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am building something with angular material. One of the pieces is to have some tabs, and stuff them with some useful information. Right now I am doing that, and populating one of the tabs with some directives in an `ng-repeat`. The only problem right now is the tabs are cutting off the elements, and I am unable to scroll downward.

Here is my html (slim)

```
md-content.md-padding
  div.registered-events[layout="row" layout-align='space-between center' layout-wrap]
    card-small.persona-card-result[object='e' ng-repeat='e in events()']
```

I can post my stuff about the styles of the elements in these tabs, but I don't think it's them that is causing the issue. I have tried the `md-dynamic-height` directive, adding `relative` to the parent and `absolute` to the children, etc, and still no luck.

Does anyone know how to add more height and make the md-tab-content scrollable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by adding this to the parent element, and the tab's parent element. The tabs were further down the chain (grandchildren elements)

**scss**

```
.grandparent {
  overflow: hidden;

  .parent {
    overflow-y: auto;

    // tabs would've been here
  }
}
```